# Stop a queue's N consumers

Tags: sql-server-2008, service-broker

I have an SSBS queue and a main process send `M` messages to the queue. There are `N` sub-processes which fetch the messages one by one and process them. The sub-processes will exit after all the messages are processed. Right now I am doing the following,

*Approach 1:*

The main process send `N` "EndOfData" after sent `M` messages. However it doesn't work well since some sub-processes may receive more than one "EndOfData" messages so some sub-processes will never get the message.

*Approach 2: (extend approach 1)*

Assign each sub-process an ID, also embed an ID in the "EndOfData" message. The sub-process rollback if the ID in the message doesn't match its ID. However, it causes "poise message" issue because of too many rollback and the queue get disable.

```
begin tran
begin try
    WAITFOR(
        RECEIVE TOP(1)
            @MessageType = message_type_name,
            @MessageBody = CAST(message_body AS xml)
        FROM
            TargetQueue
    ) , TIMEOUT 1000
    if @MessageType = 'EndOfData' and 
       @MessageBody.value('(//ID/text())[1]', 'int') <> @ID
    BEGIN 
        rollback tran
        waitfor delay '00:00:02'
    END
```

Is there a good way to implement it?

**Update:**
The sub-processes will do the following steps.

1. Receive one message
2. If "Work",

   1. process the message (may take several minutes)
   2. Send a "Info" message to the queue to info main process the message has been processed
3. If "EndOfData",

   1. Send a message "Exit" to main process
   2. Receive the`https://..../EndDialog` of "Exist" message and exit
4. If `https://.../EndDialog` of messages sent in 2.2, just receive it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following code and put the working in the transaction. So the script block can exit after receive the `EndOfData` message.

```
$conn = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection
$conn.DatabaseName = "..."
$conn.BeginTransaction()
$conn.ExecuteNonQuery("Receive message;")
# do work
$conn.CommitTransaction()
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.serverconnection.committransaction.aspx

Answer (score 1):

One more approach, supposing `N = 3`:

1. Send message of "EndOfData" type containing `3`.
2. One of 3 sub-processes receives this message, sends response message containing `2`, exits. So 2 running sub-processes left.
3. Receive response with `2` and send message of "EndOfData" type containing `2`.
4. One of 2 sub-processes receives this message, sends response message containing `1`, exits. So 1 running sub-processes left.
5. Receive response with `1` and send message of "EndOfData" type containing `1`.
6. The last running sub-process receives this message, sends response message containing `0`, exits. No running sub-processes left.
7. Receive response with `0` and stop sending messages of "EndOfData" type.